# Can you log a few commits before and after a specified commit?

Tags: git, git-log

Git log -2 {hash} will limit the output to 2 commits after the provided hash.  Is there a way to see the 2 commits that came before the has as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use

`git log --pretty=oneline --reverse --ancestory-path {sha}^..master | head -n`

where `n` is the number of commits you want.